# memory leaks on glassfish

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-leaks, glassfish

I have web app which run on `Glassfish`. There are start new threads from web app code. I run "top" command in `linux` and see list of `glassfish.jar` processes..
How to identify that, this is my thread I run from code or this system `glassfish` threads?

Second question is following:

App start and after 20-20 minutes 1-4 theads have 20-90% of CPU power(common I have 200% - 2 core)
So, How can I find memory leaks if problem stay in  my code?

Note: I could not open my app web interface, `glassfish` `admin console` and other options.

Comment: For me, that is not a memory leak problem. Maybe is a heap configuration problem

Comment: on that machine works analog app with other implemetation my code, i think problem stay in code

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beafn.html) you have documentation from Oracle on how to setup and start with profiling on Glassfish

Answer (score 0):

If the glassfish instance runs out of memory, it can't be stopped via asadmin. You have to kill it using your os tools. (kill / taskmanager / whatever).

To track down memory leaks consider using [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). You can monitor your application, take heap snapshots and search gc roots. You can also profile your application and find the hot spots (where is most time spent).

But be warned: Glassfish itself is a memory sponge and is not freeing memory properly on undeploy/redeploy. To workaround those glassfish internal issues you might use a ContextListener to poke around and free memory hooks like this one: [A ContextListener to free glassfish memory leaks](http://franke.ms/glassfish4_1_1_memory_leak.wiki)

If the threads causing your loads are your threads, reconsider your design: A JEE application must not start threads. Usually you can achieve the same functionality (starting threads) by using an EJB timer.